# Building C# (Mono) Solution from GitHub with TeamCity on CentOS

Tags: mono, centos, teamcity

I am trying to get TeamCity to do automated builds for me on CentOS, however if I create a runner type of 'MSBuild' I get the following error

```
Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find msbuild.exe at path: /usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe
```

I tried a runner type of 'Visual Studio (sln)' setting Visual Studio to be 2012 and got the following error

```
No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration.
```

When I look at my Agent Requirements, I see:

```
Unmet requirements: DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists
```

I honestly have no idea what could be wrong. Mono is up and running on this machine, as it is hosting a website built with Mono. Could somebody with a bit more experience let me know what I have done wrong please?

[EDIT]

I have just tried creating a symbolic link of where xbuild actually lives to where TeamCity wants it.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/xbuild /usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe
```

I now am getting the following error in the Build log, so I am thinking it doesn't like symbolic links.

```
[MSBuild output] Cannot open assembly '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

Comment: Have you tried reading this: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Mono+Support With what they say about mono support?

Comment: I did read that, however to me that looks like a way to change the location of where Mono lives. The path is has is the correct path for Mono itself, however the path of xbuild is not, on top of which xbuild on my machine is "xbuild" and not "xbuild.exe". Is it possible to change where it's looking for xbuild only?

Comment: I have solved this issue by calling Command Line with arguments instead, however I will keep this question open as I would like to know if there is a solution for my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this by adding an environment variable to the buildAgent.properties file on the build agent. Once you find that file add something like this in the Environment Variables section:

```
env.MSBuild=/usr/local/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/
```

I was doing this with ubuntu so that path might not be the same as what you were looking for.

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of this before, but it does work a charm! Obviously the path does vary from OS to OS, but the solution remains the same, thank you!